# HTML force "Save as" dialog for content-disposition: inline

Tags: javascript, html, angular

We are developing a web client for our API server. One resource serves files with `content-disposition: inline`. This is a customer requirement and cannot be changed. However in our administration app we want to be able to click on the link and still open the save as dialog. Is this possible with simple HTML tags?

adding `download` does not do the trick:

```
<!-- won't work -->
<a href="src" download="name">src</a>
```

Do I need to script a function for that? If so, how can I do that? We are unfortunately using angular 4 for that project...

I'm thinking, if I right click on the link and choose "Save link as" it does what I want it to do. So maybe I need to add `(click)=openSaveLinkAs()` which then will open the window?

Comment: How about proxying the file through your web server and have your web server replace that one problematic header? Can be set up with two or three lines in your web server configuration, like .htaccess for Apache…

Comment: Hm, might work but I would still like a javascript only solution